# Salesforce Community Plus Login User is not able to query User Object

Tags: community, user

```
 private List < String > getEmailAddresses() {
        User[] usrTestLst = [SELECT email FROM user ];

    List < String > idList = new List < String > ();
    List < String > mailToAddresses = new List < String > ();
    Group g = [SELECT(select userOrGroupId from groupMembers) FROM group WHERE DeveloperName = 'EU_pod_3'];
    for (GroupMember gm: g.groupMembers) {
        idList.add(gm.userOrGroupId);
    }
    User[] usr = [SELECT email FROM user WHERE id IN: idList];
    system.debug('usrList==='+ usr);
    for (User u: usr) {
        mailToAddresses.add(u.email);
    }
    return mailToAddresses;
}
```

For a Community User, an empty list is returned by above method. How can i give User Object access for a Community Plus Login user